# Push Notification to Client

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, comet

I built my project using Struts, Spring, and Hibernate. I am using Tomcat for the server. Now I want to implement push notifications in my web application, to perform tasks like updating a table on a view layer according to new data in the database, or show a notification when a certain condition occurs. How can I implement this, and what tools should I use? Maybe Comet or something similar? If you have a link to a tutorial, I would find that helpful.

I am also wondering whether this (push) is related to messaging?

I've tried [this link](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/wa-cometjava/)
but it looks like pull. My case is like a chatting application - if someone logs in, the other member will get a notification. I am confused about how to implement this.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the framework [Atmosphere](http://github.com/Atmosphere/)? It supports websocket and also fallback to mentioned longpolling.

It can be used with jquery on the client side. Tutorial is [here](https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere/wiki/Getting-Started-with-The-Atmosphere-Framework-and-WebSocket).

Answer (score 0):

Well the easiest way is use ajax calls with long polling(jQuery comes to mind). Comet is fine too.

Comment: do you have any tutorial or link? especially for a newbie

Answer (score 0):

Use Spring STOMP WebSockets.. its very easy and simple
https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-stomp-websocket/