# Implemeting push technology on Android

Tags: android, jakarta-ee, push-notification

I have a project to develop an application that implements push technology. I can save the message to a database when I add some message, but my problem is that I can't send (broadcast) the message to the client and I can't implement the client accepting the message (accept broadcast message).
I'm using Spring, Hibernate, and Tomcat for the server, and I've built the client on Android.

I have tried all the links in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13062048/push-notification-to-client?rq=1) question, but I'm still confused about how to implement the source code.

Comment: Is that the GCM service explained here http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html ?

Comment: @Timson : can you suggest other way, because in my project not use GCM or 3rd party like that, because my project's description is pushing real-time data or message. so the application can send and accept real-time message

Answer (score 0):

For GCM, an explanation is available [here](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gs.html).

For this you need to get an API key for your project from the API console.
Also, you need the Google Cloud Messaging for Android Library which will be available in your Android SDK/extras directory.

And if you are looking for both client & server side examples with explanations, they are explained nicely on [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/) blog.

Comment: i respect for your answer, but my project not use GCM or 3rd party, so can u suggest other way for  pushing real-time data or message. so the application can send and accept real-time message ?

Comment: @boeapj For the second time now, can you stop addressing me directly? I'm not the only person on this site.